# Execute multiple testng.xml simultaneously

Tags: selenium, testng

I need to run my tests in parallel but , tried to parallelize them and unfortunately it doesn't look very stable!
My new idea is to run different .xml ( one for each browser) but i need to do that in parallel 
is there any way to make this stuff? 
Right now i start my session by using ant

Answer (score 0):

You could try with:

```
java org.testng.TestNG -suitethreadpoolsize 3 testng1.xml testng2.xml testng3.xml
```

Depending on your suite, you could also add the `parallel` parameter:

```
<suite name="My suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
```

Check more info [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-running).